# "č" character in the word "Koláč" is not output

Tags: xetex, unicode

I am having problems with the "č" character in the word "Koláč" when typesetting cooking recipes. I am using XeTeX right now. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi

\title{Recepty}
\author{Václav Zeman a Ludmila Zemanová}
\date{\today}

\setHeadlines{
  inghead = Ingredience,
  prephead = Příprava,
  hinthead = Tip,
  calory = energetický obsah,
  continuationhead = Pokračování,
  continuationfoot = Pokračování na další stránce
}

\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}[
  ]{Koláč bramborový}
  \ingredients{
    \unit[30]{dkg} & vařených brambor \\
  }
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

The "č" character does not get output, while many other Czech national characters do. What can I do about it?

Comment: What input encoding are you currently using? XeTeX and LuaTeX can handle UTF-8 only.

Comment: @Mico: I am using UTF-8 for the document.

Comment: In my case it was enough to use `xltxtra` package. But the font's are a bit different, I like more the ones which are without `xltxtra` :-(.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xcookybooky` package makes wrong assumptions about fonts. But you're doing wrong too:

1. Don't use `fontenc` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX (it can be used, but not in general cases)
2. Don't use the obsolete `a4wide` package. Use `geometry` if you want to modify the page parameters.
3. Don't load `xltxtra` and `xunicode`.

The fix is simple: use the default font and encoding for the recipe title:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{xcookybooky}

\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[czech]{babel}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage[czech]{babel}
  \fi
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{czech}
  \fi
\fi

%%% Fix the setting by xcookybooky
\AtBeginDocument{
  \setRecipenameFont{\familydefault}{\encodingdefault}{b}{n}
}

\title{Recepty}
\author{Václav Zeman a Ludmila Zemanová}
\date{\today}

\setHeadlines{
  inghead = Ingredience,
  prephead = Příprava,
  hinthead = Tip,
  calory = energetický obsah,
  continuationhead = Pokračování,
  continuationfoot = Pokračování na další stránce
}

\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}[
  ]{Koláč bramborový}
  \ingredients{
    \unit[30]{dkg} & vařených brambor \\
  }
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

I've used `polyglossia` for XeLaTeX, but `babel` would work too.

“Potato cake”? Should be good. `;-)`

[image]

Comment: BTW, in TeXLive 2013 one should be able to use Polyglossia with LuaTeX too, though I didn’t test it myself.

Comment: @KhaledHosny I know Élie Roux is doing work on it; I didn't test it myself. I will try.