# Customization of biblatex style - same as natbib plainnat

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Before switch to `biblatex`, I was using `bibtex` like this:

```
\usepackage[round, semicolon, authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

I'd like to get the very same style with `biblatex` (without usage of `natbib` backward compatibility).

In the text, in case of two authors, I wish only "Smith and Jones (2017)" (as `\citet`) or "(Smith and Jones 2017)" (as `\citep`). I don't mind if there is "et" or "&" instead of "and". In case of 3 and more authors, I wish only "Smith et al. (2017)" (as `\citet`) or "(Smith et al., 2017)" (as `\citep`).

In the bibliography listing, I wish all authors, and I'd prefer the title to be bold and not in quotes, but I can live without it.

All this was very straightforward with `natbib` above and `citet`/`citep`, but I can't figure out how to reach it in with `biblatex`/`biber`. My main reason to switch to `biblatex` was basically no reasonable way how to [sort accented characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432006/wrong-order-of-references-in-bibliography-with-diacritical-characters) with `bibtex`.

Simply, in the best case, it should look like following picture:

[image: References]

Some settings (like back referenes) I managed to set, but for the above I really do struggle...

I also must say I like more some features of `biblatex`, like clickable DOI or back references "(cit. on p. XX)".

Problematic working example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[autostyle=true, english=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
bibstyle=authortitle,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
autocite=inline,
sorting=ynt,
sortcase=true,
sortcites=true,
maxbibnames=100,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=2,
hyperref=true,
backref=true,
backrefstyle=none,
maxalphanames=1
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor={Firebrick4},
anchorcolor={Blue4},
citecolor={Green4},
filecolor={DeepPink4},
menucolor={Chocolate4},
urlcolor={DodgerBlue4},
bookmarks=true,
pdfencoding=auto,
unicode=true,
xetex
]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{Shaw2005,
author={Shaw, Joey and Lickey, Edgar B and Beck, John T and Farmer, Susan B and Liu, Wusheng and Miller, Jermey and Siripun, K C and Winder, Charles T and Schilling, Edward E and Small, Ramdall L},
doi={10.3732/ajb.92.1.142},
issn={0002-9122},
journal={American Journal of Botany},
month={01},
number={1},
pages={142--166},
title={{The tortoise and the hare II: relative utility of 21 noncoding chloroplast DNA sequences for phylogenetic analysis}},
url={https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.3732/ajb.92.1.142},
volume={92},
year={2005}
}
@article{Shaw2007,
author={Shaw, Joey and Lickey, Edgar B and Schilling, Edward E and Small, Ramdall L},
doi={10.3732/ajb.94.3.275},
issn={0002-9122},
journal={American Journal of Botany},
month={03},
number={3},
pages={275--288},
title={{Comparison of whole chloroplast genome sequences to choose noncoding regions for phylogenetic studies in angiosperms: the tortoise and the hare III}},
url={https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.3732/ajb.94.3.275},
volume={94},
year={2007}
}
\end{filecontents}
XXX \textcite{Shaw2005} XXX \textcite{Shaw2007} XXX \textcite{Shaw2005,Shaw2007}, XXX \parencite{Shaw2005} XXX \parencite{Shaw2007} XXX  \parencite{Shaw2005,Shaw2007} XXX.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It renders as:

[image: Wrong format of references.]

There should be only "Shaw et al (2005)" and so on. Only one name before "et al", no more.

Comment: While it is possible to emulate `plainnat` (at least in theory - I have never done it), doing that in full detail is going to be a lot of work. But if you can live with small differences it should be doable. Many bits and pieces of the puzzle are already answered elsewhere on this site. Just search and you'll find it.

Comment: I think several questions each asking about one specific thing you have trouble with would be more valuable to this site than just one big question that essentially is: Please emulate this style. In any way, please add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows what you have so far to your question. An MWE makes sure we are all talking about the same thing and helps us to get started helping you more quickly.

Comment: This is intended behaviour: `biblatex` normally does not abbreviate author lists in a way that they could get ambiguous. You can turn off that feature with `uniquelist=false,`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864

Comment: It is not really clear, but if your only problem is the "... et al." name lists, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/105447.

Comment: A few other things: `bibstyle=authortitle, citestyle=authoryear-comp,` is a slightly unusual combination. Normally author-year citation styles are combined with author-year bibliography styles. With the author-title style that is currently used the year is not very prominent and is harder to find in the bibliography making it difficult to find the correct entry for a particular citation. `sorting=ynt,` adds another layer of difficulty: It sorts by year, name and title. But one would normally expect name, year, title with those citations ...

Comment: `sortcase=true,` is the default (normally I wouldn't dream of changing the value of the `sortcase` option, whatever the default value). `sortcites=true,` is already issued by `citestyle=authoryear-comp,`. `hyperref=true,` is no better than the default `hyperref=auto,` (they only differ in their behaviour if `hyperref` is not loaded: `true` displays a warning in that case, `auto` does nothing - if `hyperref` is not loaded *neither* of the two actually turns on links). `maxalphanames=1` is not used by the style you use, it is only relevant for `alphabetic` styles.

Comment: Thank You, @moeve for Your comments pointing me to the right places. I can now solve everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help and good point by @moeve, I can solve it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel} % Languages
\usepackage{filecontents} % Included exemplary file
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} % Color names
\usepackage[ % Bibliography settings
backend=biber,
bibstyle=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear-comp,
autocite=inline,
maxbibnames=100,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=2,
hyperref=true,
backref=true,
backrefstyle=none,
uniquelist=false
]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}} % Bold article title
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage[ % Links settings
breaklinks=true,
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor={Firebrick4},
anchorcolor={Blue4},
citecolor={Green4},
filecolor={DeepPink4},
menucolor={Chocolate4},
urlcolor={DodgerBlue4},
bookmarks=true,
pdfencoding=auto,
unicode=true,
xetex
]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
% Exemplary bibliography
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{Shaw2005,
author={Shaw, Joey and Lickey, Edgar B and Beck, John T and Farmer, Susan B and Liu, Wusheng and Miller, Jermey and Siripun, K C and Winder, Charles T and Schilling, Edward E and Small, Ramdall L},
doi={10.3732/ajb.92.1.142},
issn={0002-9122},
journal={American Journal of Botany},
month={01},
number={1},
pages={142--166},
title={{The tortoise and the hare II: relative utility of 21 noncoding chloroplast DNA sequences for phylogenetic analysis}},
url={https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.3732/ajb.92.1.142},
volume={92},
year={2005}
}
@article{Shaw2007,
author={Shaw, Joey and Lickey, Edgar B and Schilling, Edward E and Small, Ramdall L},
doi={10.3732/ajb.94.3.275},
issn={0002-9122},
journal={American Journal of Botany},
month={03},
number={3},
pages={275--288},
title={{Comparison of whole chloroplast genome sequences to choose noncoding regions for phylogenetic studies in angiosperms: the tortoise and the hare III}},
url={https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.3732/ajb.94.3.275},
volume={94},
year={2007}
}
\end{filecontents}
% The document
XXX \textcite{Shaw2005} XXX \textcite{Shaw2007} XXX \textcite{Shaw2007,Shaw2005}, XXX \parencite{Shaw2005} XXX \parencite{Shaw2007} XXX  \parencite{Shaw2007,Shaw2005} XXX.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code.]

Comment: Try with `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}`, i.e. `\mkbibbold` instead of `\textbf`.

Comment: @moeve I did, but I don't see any difference. What is the purpose here?

Comment: `\mkbibbold` is the `biblatex` wrapper around `\textbf` that can interface with the `punctfont` option of `biblatex`. In the context of `biblatex` styles it is good practice to use the wrappers provided by `biblatex` even if there is no change in the output.

Comment: AFAIK `xlextra` and `xunicode` should not be loaded any more, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347618/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117508/35864. I doubt you really need `metalogo`. `polyglossia` does not work entirely smoothly with `biblatex` and has not been properly developed in a while (there is a release from April 2018, but that does not address many open bugs), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864. If you mainly write in languages with an (extended) Latin alphabet, you don't need `polyglossia`, `babel` is fine.

Comment: Indeed, `xunicode` is not required. I'm not sure about `xlxtra`, thought (it also loads 3 following characters - `fontspec`, `realscripts` and  `metalogo`). Currently, I'm unable to compile my document without it. It will require deeper exploration. `polyglossia` seems to work fine for me now (I need bilingual content), but I'll try how it works with `babel`.

Comment: You already load `fontspec` and `realscript` separately, so `xltxtra` doesn't really add anything in that regard. I also have a hard time imagining why you would need `metalogo`: Do you write `\LaTeX` and `\XeLaTeX` a lot in your document? `polyglossia` works fine until it does not, if you stick to European languages (and even in other cases, but I assume that already has you covered) `babel` is definitely the better choice because it is more mature and actively maintained. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432347/35864 explains why `polyglossia` and `biblatex` don't really work well together

Comment: ... even if it seems to work fine.

Comment: `polyglossia` to `babel` was easy switch. It works well. And thank You, @moeve the link describes it well. As `xltxtra` loads the other packages automatically, I prefer to list them explicitly to see it. Also, I don't really see what is wrong with is usage, especially as without it I can't compile whole documents (problems with graphics, font sizes, etc.). I agree it doesn't have to be part of MWE here.

Comment: I don't know explicit details, but I trust egreg's judgement when he says that `xltxtra` should not be used. In fact I rarely see documents using it any more. I also think that if you load `fontspec` and `realscripts` `xltxtra` does not really do a lot of things an average document would need. I don't think that loading packages explicitly that are already loaded by other packages is a particularly prudent practice. You could end up with [option clashes](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-optionclash.html) and it makes the preamble unnecessarily long.

Comment: @moewe I edited the MWE to drop the `xltxtra` etc. It is unneeded here. Regarding my usage it in full document, it does require more work and it is definitely topic for another question. Thank You for all Your help.